# Updating an existing content type field link by JSOM

Tags: 2013, content-type, client-object-model, csom

I have a content type and I would like to set some field links to hidden.
The code runs perfectly, but for some reason, when I check in the UI if the field link is hidden, the changes are not applied.

```
...
var fieldLinksEnumerator = currFieldlinks.getEnumerator();
while (fieldLinksEnumerator.moveNext()) {
   var currentItem = fieldLinksEnumerator.get_current();
   currentItem.set_hidden(true);
}
...
// Update content type
currContenttype.update(true);
...
context.executeQueryAsync(...
```

Anybody any ideas?

Comment: If I execute the code in the host web it works. Using the same code (+ code for cross domain) in the app web (and updating fieldlinks in the host web) it does not update the values of the field links.